# How to access Flink statefun function

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-statefun

flink playground gives a demo as below:

```
public final class GreeterAppServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StatefulFunctions functions = new StatefulFunctions();
    functions.withStatefulFunction(UserFn.SPEC);
    functions.withStatefulFunction(GreetingsFn.SPEC);

    final RequestReplyHandler requestReplyHandler = functions.requestReplyHandler();
    final Undertow httpServer =
        Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(1108, "0.0.0.0")
            .setHandler(new UndertowHttpHandler(requestReplyHandler))
            .build();
    httpServer.start();
  }
```

how to access the function by a http request?
post?get?

Comment: You can find the complete documentation at statefun.io, and in the playground try `docker-compose up`

Comment: statefun master will access the http server's endpoint specified in `urlPathTemplate` of `io.statefun.endpoints.v2/http` spec in `module.yaml`. it's going to be a POST request because master needs to use request body to send byte array

Answer (score 1):

When you set your stateful function like this

```
functions.withStatefulFunction(UserFn.SPEC);
```

you actually register your function as a handler to http server.

Next thing you have to do is to define which endpoint your function will be using.

```
  static final TypeName TYPENAME = TypeName.typeNameOf("greeter.fns", "user");
  static final StatefulFunctionSpec SPEC =
      StatefulFunctionSpec.builder(TYPENAME)
          .withValueSpecs(SEEN_COUNT, SEEN_TIMESTAMP_MS)
          .withSupplier(UserFn::new)
          .build();
```

In the example above, stateful function is registered to the endpoint `greeter.fns/user`. Ref: https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun-playground/blob/main/java/greeter/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/statefun/playground/java/greeter/UserFn.java

This should also be defined in your `module.yaml` file as below. Ref: https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun-playground/blob/main/java/greeter/module.yaml

```
functions: greeter.fns/*
```

Finally, you configure your module.yaml as an environment in your `docker-compose.yml`. Ref: https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun-playground/blob/main/java/greeter/docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - ./module.yaml:/module.yaml
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question